# How to set up a "settimeout" properly for a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope I can get some help. I'm new to Jquery and JavaScript and I got stuck with a "setTimeout" function.
I'm working on my navigation bar and basically I need a div(sub menu) to fade in when "click" on an anchor tag, fade it out if you move the mouse to a different navigation link and hide it all together if the mouse leaves it: like so:

1. show on click but hide it after a couple of seconds
2. hide if after the mouse leaves the div.

This is what I've got so far:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $("#sub_nav").fadeIn(400);
});

$("#sub_nav").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(0);
});

$("#sub_nav").mouseenter(function() {
    if(this) {
        $(this).show(0);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(0);
        }, 2000);
    };
});
```

It works as expected except for the `setTimeout`.

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: I don't think `if (this)` ever got to be false.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#sub_nav").mouseenter(function() {
    if ( !$(this).is(':animated') ) {
        var el = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(el).fadeOut(0);
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

'this' inside the scope of the function fed is the 'window' object, you need to save the reference to the element.

I removed your if(this) because it would always evaluate to true and I wasn't sure if you were debugging, but you can probably use this as an example if it isn't the correct solution.

Comment: Thanks Meder, I was not expecting an answer so quick. I tried your suggestion and it does not seem to accomplish what I need. I have not tried to debug it either. I'll try to explain it better.
If the link is clicked, the submenu fades in, if the mouse goes into the submenu then it stays displayed, if not then the submenu fades out after a couple of seconds. Or the mouse goes into the submenu and fades out when it leaves it.
That's why I tried the "if" statement. Any ideas?
 Thanks

Comment: Lol - the description is kind of confusing but I added an if around my code so if it's not being animated ( from the fadeIn ) it will fadeOut. I'm not even sure my logic is correct at this point, do you have an example you can throw on jsbin.com?

Comment: Sorry, I sometimes it's hard to put it in words. If you want you can take a look at it here: http://173.9.165.254/sites/www.madphotoge.com/
, the submenu shows if you click on "Releases".
Even if I have to think of something else I'm grateful for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I did not know what you meant by jsbin.com. Shame on me!

Comment: That works, though I'm a little too sleepy ATM but you can probably use the `:animated` selector, reference to the element, `.is` and possibly `.data` which I have in my example ( except for the latter ).